# Best way to make a child object from a list self convert into other child of same parent

Tags: c++, oop, templates, design-patterns, vector

I have a list of pointers to objects from Parent

```
vector<Parent*> list;
```

then I have 2 child Classes of Parent: Child1 and Child2 that are added to the list.

The code runs through all entities of the list and calls Execute();

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    list[i]->Execute();
```

Execute() is a virtual function of Parent and is implemented differently in each child class. I want to make a condition **inside the function of Child1::Execute()** in which it is replaced by an entity of **Child2** at the same position in the list.

of course I cant do this:

```
void Child1::Execute() {
    ...
    if(condition)
        this = new Child2();
}
```

But I cant figure out a good solution that does this. In the end there will be a few hundred Other Child classes from Parent that will do the same but in other conditions, so I wanted a good expandable solution.

Thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps post a full sample of your code... even if it does not compile. It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking. Further more are you perhaps talking about derived classes rather than child classes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From my understanding and according to [this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Inheritance) a child class **is** a class that was derived from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you cannot replace the current object with another object. You have to move this action outside of `Execute`.

For a vector of pointers:

```
Parent* Child1::Execute() {
    ...
    return condition ? new Child2 : this;
}

newobj = list[i]->Execute();
if (newobj != list[i]) {
  delete list[i];
  list[i] = newobj;
}
```

For a vector of suitable *smart* pointers it's a bit more concise:

```
list[i] = list[i]->Execute();
```

Comment: this is exactly was I was looking for! Thanks!